# Is there any function like `isfile`, `exists` or `-e` in gdb?

Tags: gdb

I want to write a subprocess in *.gdbinit* for gdb. So I need some test like `isfile`, `exists` or `-e`. Are there any built-in function or any other method to implement it?

Comment: Have you considered the documentation?

Answer (score 4):

No, there isn't anything like that.

You can either use "shell" to invoke shell scripts, or you can use the "python" command to evaluate Python code.

Comment: Using shell can only get the result printed, but no saved return code that may be used to control a conditional flow. How about python?

Comment: Python is more fully integrated.  However, note that it can be done with "shell" -- it is just gross.  The trick is to have your shell script write out a gdb script that is then "source"d.